# Para un trabajo de Biología estoy intentando crear una formula que analice automáticamente unos resultados y me diga si están mal, bien o normal

Tags: python

Para un trabajo de Biología estoy intentando crear una formula que analice automáticamente unos resultados y me diga si están mal, bien o normal. Por ejemplo: El nivel de hemoglobina de un paciente es de 5,5 millones, y los valores normales están entre 4,5 y 6,5. Lo que la formula debería devolverme es que los resultados son normales ya que se encuentran en el rango de 4,5 millones y 6,5 millones. Ejemplo 2: El nivel de hemoglobina de un paciente es de 4,0 millones, y teniendo en cuenta el rango de lo que seria un nivel normal, el paciente, esta por debajo. Lo que la formula debería devolverme es que los resultados son bajos y por lo tanto malos.

Soy nuevo en Python y estuve investigando y mirando muchos videos para ver como se hacia pero no pude lograr nada. Solo pude armar un menú en donde podes elegir que queres ver (ya sea hemoglobina o otra cosa) y después de eso te pide que pongas el nivel de hemoglobina. Solo me falta este calculo final, gracias :D

[image: Imagen de todo o que llegue ahora]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que tu codigo está en imagen y que estoy en un celular, no copié igual tu codigo, solo una parte. Tu problema se resuelve con un simple `if`

```py
print("opciones del menu")
print("1.- Hematies o eritrocitos")
print("2.- hemoglobina")
...

op = int(input("ingrese la opción "))
if op in range(1,4): #el 4 representa el máximo de opciones 
     if op == 2:
          #convertimos el valor en un float para poder evaluarlo 
          valores = float(input("ingrese los valores "))
          #evaluamis los valores 
          if 4.5<= valores <= 6.5:
               print("valores normales")
          elif valores > 6.5:
               print("valores muy altos")
          elif valores < 4.5:
               print("valores muy bajos")
else:
     print("Saliendo...")
```

Answer (score 0):

En esta solución definimos una tabla de rangos usando una lista (o tupla), donde registramos el valor inicial de cada rango. Para el caso de la hemoglobina, sería:

```
hemo = (0, 4_500_000, 6_500_000)
```

Definimos también una función que dado un valor y una tabla de rangos, te dice en que posición se encuentra dentro del rango (0, 1, ...) y cual es el valor inicial del mismo:

```
def busca_rango(iter, valor):
    posicion = 0
    prev = None
    for val in iter:
        if posicion and val > valor:
            break
        prev = val
        posicion += 1

    return posicion - 1, prev
```

Para simplificar el código, creamos otra lista con los mensajes asociados a los rangos, que usamos para imprimir la evaluación

```
hemo_mensajes = ["Valores muy bajos", "Valores normales", "Valores muy altos"]
while True:
    op = int(input("ingrese la opción "))
    if op in range(1,4): #el 4 representa el máximo de opciones
         if op == 2:
             #convertimos el valor en un float para poder evaluarlo
             valores = float(input("ingrese los valores "))
             posicion, base = busca_rango(hemo, valores)
             print(hemo_mensajes[posicion])
    else:
         print("Saliendo...")
         break
```

produce:

```
ingrese la opción 2
ingrese los valores 5000
Valores muy bajos
ingrese la opción 2
ingrese los valores 600000000
Valores muy altos
```